# GROUP BY, SUM, ORDER BY, then LIMIT database data with mssql_query()

Tags: php, sql-server, grouping, limit

I have this array push from sql query.

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
[TICK] => 1015 
    [KD_AIRL] => GA 
    [JUM] => 2834763198 )
[1] => Array ( 
[TICK] => 266 
    [KD_AIRL] => JT 
    [JUM] => 382940267 ) 
[2] => Array ( 
[TICK] => 153 
    [KD_AIRL] => SJY 
    [JUM] => 321328100 ) 
[3] => Array ( 
[TICK] => 672 
    [KD_AIRL] => GA 
    [JUM] => 1131468200.51 ) 
[4] => Array ( 
[TICK] => 239 
    [KD_AIRL] => JT 
    [JUM] => 229913500.25 ) 
[5] => Array ( 
[TICK] => 95 
    [KD_AIRL] => SJY 
    [JUM] => 102319151.00 ) 
)
```

From array above, I want to group by [KD_AIRL] to be like this :

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
[TICK] => 1687 
    [KD_AIRL] => GA 
    [JUM] => 3966231398 )
[1] => Array ( 
[TICK] => 505 
    [KD_AIRL] => JT 
    [JUM] => 612853767 ) 
[2] => Array ( 
[TICK] => 248 
    [KD_AIRL] => SJY 
    [JUM] => 423647251 ) 
)
```

And then after group by [KD_AIRL], I want limit that array DESC by [JUM]. So array should be like this :
(example, i want limit 2 row)

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
[TICK] => 1687 
    [KD_AIRL] => GA 
    [JUM] => 3966231398 )
[1] => Array ( 
[TICK] => 505 
    [KD_AIRL] => JT 
    [JUM] => 612853767 ) 
)
```

What should i do in php code?

**UPDATE**
This is my php code to select from all branch databases in sql server 2000.

```
<?php
...
...
include "../../../config/dbreportis.php";
// Query for select name branch (NM_BRANCH) and its name database (NM_DATA) in server
$cbranch = mssql_query("SELECT NM_DATA, NM_BRANCH FROM Branch ORDER BY KD_BRANCH ASC");
while ($allbranch = mssql_fetch_array($cbranch)){
// Connect to each branches database (NM_DATA) 
include "../../../config/db.php";
mssql_select_db($allbranch[NM_DATA]);

// Query for selecting all customer and all airline
if (($customer == 'all_customer') AND ($airl == 'all_airline')){
$kueri = "
SELECT     TOP $batas COUNT(d.TICKNO) AS TICK, d.KD_AIRL, SUM(d.FARE + d.TAXIW +   
d.VATVAL + d.TRANSFEE - d.DISVAL) AS JUM
FROM         DInvoiceT d INNER JOIN
HINVOICE h ON h.INVNO = d.INVNO AND h.SRK = d.SRK LEFT OUTER JOIN
Airline a ON a.KD_AIRL = d.KD_AIRL 
WHERE     (h.INVDATE >= '$from') AND (h.INVDATE <= '$to') AND (h.INOUT = '$inout')  
AND (h.SRK = 'TX') AND (h.CPRINT = 'Y') AND (h.SVD = '')
GROUP BY d.KD_AIRL
ORDER BY JUM DESC";
}
// Query for selecting all customer but specific airline
elseif (($customer == 'all_customer') AND ($airl != 'all_airline')){
$kueri = "
SELECT     TOP $batas COUNT(d.TICKNO) AS TICK, d.KD_AIRL, SUM(d.FARE + d.TAXIW +   
d.VATVAL + d.TRANSFEE - d.DISVAL) AS JUM
FROM         DInvoiceT d INNER JOIN
HINVOICE h ON h.INVNO = d.INVNO AND h.SRK = d.SRK LEFT OUTER JOIN
Airline a ON a.KD_AIRL = d.KD_AIRL 
WHERE     (h.INVDATE >= '$from') AND (h.INVDATE <= '$to') AND (h.INOUT = '$inout') AND 
(h.SRK = 'TX')  AND (d.KD_AIRL = '$airl') AND (h.CPRINT = 'Y') AND (h.SVD = '')
GROUP BY d.KD_AIRL
ORDER BY JUM DESC";
}
$ticket= 0;
$sumvalue = 0;
$data = mssql_query($kueri);

while ($r = mssql_fetch_assoc($data)){
$nm_airl = mssql_query("SELECT NM_AIRL FROM Airline WHERE KD_AIRL = '$r[KD_AIRL]'");
$do_airl = mssql_fetch_array($nm_airl);
if ($do_airl['NM_AIRL'] == ''){
$nama_airline = '';
}elseif ($do_airl['NM_AIRL'] != ''){
$nama_airline = $do_airl['NM_AIRL'];
}
$do_nama_airline = "$r[KD_AIRL]-$nama_airline";
echo "<tr>
<td align='left'>$no</td>
<td align='left'>$do_nama_airline</td>
<td align='right'>$r[TICK]</td>
<td align='right'>".number_format($r[JUM], 2 , '.' , ',' );
echo "</td>
</tr>";
$ticket += $r['TICK'];
$sumvalue += $r['JUM'];
$ticket_all += $r['TICK'];
$sumvalue_all += $r['JUM'];
$no++;
} 
if ($sumvalue > 0){
echo "<tr>
<td colspan='2' align='right'>Total $airline1 :</td>
<td align='right'>".number_format($ticket, 2 , '.' , ',' );
echo "</td>
<td align='right'>".number_format($sumvalue, 2 , '.' , ',' );
echo "</td>
</tr>";
}
}
echo "<tr>
<td colspan='2' align='right'>Grand Total</td>
<td align='right'>".number_format($ticket_all, 2 , '.' , ',' );
echo "</td>
<td align='right'>".number_format($sumvalue_all, 2 , '.' , ',' );
echo "</td>
</tr>";
echo "</table>";
mssql_close();
?>
```

By that code above, if i have 20 branches and want to show top 20 result, script will give a result 20*20 = 400 row. But what i want is a report which is show 20 row and also group by [KD_AIRL] and sorted DESC by [JUM].

So I try to push query result from script above to new array and then group it by [KD_AIRL] and sort DESC by [JUM] and finally limit it to 20 (for example).

**NB**
When i use solution script below, not all [KD_AIRL] Grouped (eq [GA] repeated again):
This result taken from all branches database in sql server.

```
Array
(
    [GA ] => Array
    (
        [TICK] => 1863
        [KD_AIRL] => GA 
        [JUM] => 3906190760.99
    )

    [JT ] => Array
    (
        [TICK] => 787
        [KD_AIRL] => JT 
        [JUM] => 723166135.39
    )

    [SJY] => Array
    (
        [TICK] => 138
        [KD_AIRL] => SJY
        [JUM] => 164732319
    )

    [GAC] => Array
    (
        [TICK] => 101
        [KD_AIRL] => GAC
        [JUM] => 145669200
    )

    [GA] => Array
    (
        [TICK] => 52
        [KD_AIRL] => GA
        [JUM] => 60380240
    )

    [KP ] => Array
    (
        [TICK] => 29
        [KD_AIRL] => KP 
        [JUM] => 31069700
    )

    [JT] => Array
    (
        [TICK] => 41
        [KD_AIRL] => JT
        [JUM] => 31058000
    )

    [QG ] => Array
    (
        [TICK] => 46
        [KD_AIRL] => QG 
        [JUM] => 30951350.57
    )

    [ID ] => Array
    (
        [TICK] => 36
        [KD_AIRL] => ID 
        [JUM] => 22508000
    )

    [MZ ] => Array
    (
        [TICK] => 26
        [KD_AIRL] => MZ 
        [JUM] => 22081400
    )

    [AK ] => Array
    (
        [TICK] => 23
        [KD_AIRL] => AK 
        [JUM] => 21385468
    )

    [TGN] => Array
    (
        [TICK] => 26
        [KD_AIRL] => TGN
        [JUM] => 20125400
    )

    [QZ ] => Array
    (
        [TICK] => 17
        [KD_AIRL] => QZ 
        [JUM] => 12856500
    )

    [QZ] => Array
    (
        [TICK] => 11
        [KD_AIRL] => QZ
        [JUM] => 8810000
    )

    [IW ] => Array
    (
        [TICK] => 4
        [KD_AIRL] => IW 
        [JUM] => 6965000
    )

    [RI ] => Array
    (
        [TICK] => 6
        [KD_AIRL] => RI 
        [JUM] => 6494800
    )

    [IL ] => Array
    (
        [TICK] => 7
        [KD_AIRL] => IL 
        [JUM] => 5572000
    )

    [SI ] => Array
    (
        [TICK] => 6
        [KD_AIRL] => SI 
        [JUM] => 5260800
    )

    [6N ] => Array
    (
        [TICK] => 6
        [KD_AIRL] => 6N 
        [JUM] => 4187520
    )

    [MV ] => Array
    (
        [TICK] => 2
        [KD_AIRL] => MV 
        [JUM] => 3225735
    )

)
```

What i need is all [KD_AIRL] grouped and sorted DESC and finnaly limited to 20 row (for example).
It would be nice, if there is a way to get report i wanted just by sql query not in php code. Please give me a solution to this case. Thanks a lot.

Comment: why can't you do a `group by` and `limit` in the query itself.

Comment: because i do query for multiple databases. And if i want select top 20 (for example), then let's say i have 20 database, so query will give me 20(database) * 20 (row i want to see) = 200 row. but i just want to get 20 row...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Code

```
<?php
// Your mysql result
$myArray = Array ( 0 => Array ('TICK' => 1015, 'KD_AIRL' => 'GA','JUM' => 2834763198 ),
                 1 => Array ('TICK' => 266 ,'KD_AIRL' => 'JT','JUM' => 382940267 ) ,
                 2 => Array ('TICK' => 153 ,'KD_AIRL' => 'SJY','JUM' => 321328100 ),
                 3 => Array ('TICK' => 672,'KD_AIRL' => 'GA','JUM' => 1131468200.00 ),
                 4 => Array ('TICK' => 239,'KD_AIRL' => 'JT','JUM' => 229913500.00 ) ,
                 5 => Array ('TICK' => 95,'KD_AIRL' => 'SJY','JUM' => 102319151.00 ) );

// Some Variables are declare here               
$sumArray = array();
$getAllData = array();
$final_result = array();

// *********** Some Function **************************
// Sum, your array
function sum_array($myArray){
    $return = array();
    foreach ($myArray as $k=>$subsumArray) {
      foreach ($subsumArray as $id=>$value) {

        if($id == 'KD_AIRL'){
            $return[$id] =$value;
        }else{
            $return[$id]+=$value;
        }
      }
    }
return $return;      

}
//////////////////////
function cmp($a, $b) {

    $a = $a['JUM'];
    $b = $b['JUM'];

    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? 1 : -1;
}
//***********************************************************

foreach ($myArray as $k=>$subArray) {
    $getAllData[$subArray['KD_AIRL']][] = $subArray;            
}

// Replace below code with old new(changes baove code)
$new_array = array();
foreach ($getAllData as $key => $Data_val){

    if (!array_key_exists($key, $final_result)) {
       $final_result[$key] = sum_array($Data_val);
       $new_array[] =  sum_array($Data_val);
    }   
}


uasort($new_array, 'cmp');


// Set limit
$limit = 2;
$oupout=array_slice($new_array,0,$limit);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($oupout);
echo "</pre>";
exit;

?>
```

Comment: Hi Mandip Darji, i already try your code above. But still it doesn group [KD_AIRL]. Such as GA repeted twice like this :  [0] => Array ( [TICK] => 2888 [KD_AIRL] => GA [JUM] => 6032060368.01 )  [4] => Array ( [TICK] => 96 [KD_AIRL] => GA [JUM] => 116942500 ). Example : 0 => Array ('TICK' => 1015, 'KD_AIRL' => 'GA','JUM' => 2834763198 ). I want it group by 'GA' value.. how is the way to fix this sir?

Comment: @kroseva, i am not getting you what are you telling, Check below your exacted and my result. Your exacted result is ==>Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
[TICK] => 1687 
    [KD_AIRL] => GA 
    [JUM] => 3966231398 )
[1] => Array ( 
[TICK] => 505 
    [KD_AIRL] => JT 
    [JUM] => 612853767 ) 
) My Result Array
(
    [GA] => Array
        (
            [TICK] => 1687
            [KD_AIRL] => GA
            [JUM] => 3966231398
        )

    [JT] => Array
        (
            [TICK] => 505
            [KD_AIRL] => JT
            [JUM] => 612853767
        )

)

Comment: ,if data array is like that, your script is correct sir. but when i try to actual database, it does'nt group all KD_AIRL sir. This is my actual sql result : [link]https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bx_YKyiWwVwMNFRzaVoxc3BxNGM

Comment: and i want limit it 20 row only.. How to fix this sir?

Comment: hi @kroseva .. check this link :- https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4_jly0AxCqpM1dZVUJJa1RXMmc/edit?usp=sharing         working or not ?

Comment: it seems that link above doesnt work anymore :(.. But when i analyze your code again, why my result from actual query result doesnt match with my expected result cos it's KD_AIRL such GA was like this : [GA ] and [GA] (there was space in key, so [GA] repeated twice. I really appreciated your help and reply sir, thanks a lot for spending your time to help and reply my comment :)

Comment: hummm.....that's grate ...finally you got solution.....if above code is help to you, plz like above answer...

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem can be solve by groupby and limit in SQL.

But... If you really wish for php code here is it.

```
$array = Array(); // YOUR DATA

// get `KD_AIRL` as list
$result = array();
foreach($array as $item){
    if(!in_array($item['KD_AIRL'], $result)){
        $result[$item['KD_AIRL']] = array(
            'TICK' => 0,
            'KD_AIRL' => $item['KD_AIRL'],
            'JMP' => 0
        );
      }
}

// group TRICK and JMP
foreach($array as $item){
    if(isset($result[$item['KD_AIRL']])){
        $result[$item['KD_AIRL']]['TICK'] += $item['TICK'];
        $result[$item['KD_AIRL']]['JMP'] += $item['JMP'];
    }
}

// sort by JMP DESC
function cmp($a, $b) {

    $a = $a['JMP'];
    $b = $b['JMP'];

    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? 1 : -1;
}
uasort($array, 'cmp');

// get by limit
$limit = 2;
array_slice($array, $limit-1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution :). I use foreach($array as $row) to display the result but it doesn't give a result i wanted :(. Could you help me how to display a result from your code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to slove it by Mysql Function GroupBy,Sum and Limit ,

Can you plz tell me ur your table structre and you sql query.

```
<?php
// Your mysql result
$myArray = Array ( 0 => Array ('TICK' => 1015, 'KD_AIRL' => 'GA','JUM' => 2834763198 ),
                 1 => Array ('TICK' => 266 ,'KD_AIRL' => 'JT','JUM' => 382940267 ) ,
                 2 => Array ('TICK' => 153 ,'KD_AIRL' => 'SJY','JUM' => 321328100 ),
                 3 => Array ('TICK' => 672,'KD_AIRL' => 'GA','JUM' => 1131468200.00 ),
                 4 => Array ('TICK' => 239,'KD_AIRL' => 'JT','JUM' => 229913500.00 ) ,
                 5 => Array ('TICK' => 95,'KD_AIRL' => 'SJY','JUM' => 102319151.00 ) );

// Some Variables are declare here               
$sumArray = array();
$getAllData = array();
$final_result = array();

// *********** Some Function **************************
// Sum, your array
function sum_array($myArray){
    $return = array();
    foreach ($myArray as $k=>$subsumArray) {
      foreach ($subsumArray as $id=>$value) {

        if($id == 'KD_AIRL'){
            $return[$id] =$value;
        }else{
            $return[$id]+=$value;
        }
      }
    }
return $return;      

}
//////////////////////
function cmp($a, $b) {

    $a = $a['JUM'];
    $b = $b['JUM'];

    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? 1 : -1;
}
//***********************************************************

foreach ($myArray as $k=>$subArray) {
    $getAllData[$subArray['KD_AIRL']][] = $subArray;            
}


foreach ($getAllData as $key => $Data_val){

    if (!array_key_exists($key, $final_result)) {
       $final_result[$key] = sum_array($Data_val);  
    }   
}

uasort($final_result, 'cmp');

// Set limit
$limit = 2;
$oupout=array_slice($final_result,0,$limit);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($oupout);
echo "</pre>";
exit;

?>
```

Your OutPut

---

```
<pre>Array
(
    [GA] => Array
        (
            [TICK] => 1687
            [KD_AIRL] => GA
            [JUM] => 3966231398
        )

    [JT] => Array
        (
            [TICK] => 505
            [KD_AIRL] => JT
            [JUM] => 612853767
        )

)
</pre>
```

---

Comment: If [JUM] value is float (not integer), is that code still can group array by [KD_AIRL] ? Because [JUM] value can be float. I'll appreciate to hear your solution.. Nb : I use sql server 2000

Comment: thax Ronal, it's working or not ?  ....it's working fine with Float value also, can u plz share your table & sql query ?....it will also try using query......bcoz i thing it's a easy way.....what u say..?

Comment: it work but not all [KD_AIRL] grouped. For example you can see in my edited post above. for [KD_AIRL] = GA which should be display once, but it is displayed two times. So can you give me how to fix this? I know how to solve this case if the query against single database. The problem is query (you can see in my edited post above) against multiple databases.. How can I group and sort plus limit it if query against multiple database in php? Please help me..

Comment: hi ronal. not able see your changes in above...can u plz tell what changes u have done..? and GA is not dosplayed two times......

Comment: hi Mandip Darji, i have update my sql query in php script before i'm doing array push to new array. When i push to new array, [GA] displayed twice.. You can see my edited post above

Comment: @RonalDamanik,no dear, are you talking about ==> $oupout array key ?

Comment: yes.. oupout array key were double. i want it grouped.. how to fix this sir?

Comment: // Replace below code with old new(changes baove code)
$new_array = array();
foreach ($getAllData as $key => $Data_val){

    if (!array_key_exists($key, $final_result)) {
       $final_result[$key] = sum_array($Data_val);
       $new_array[] =  sum_array($Data_val);
    }   
}
$oupout= $new_array;

Comment: I still can not get what i wanted :( this is my 20 result from multiple databases : Array ( [GA ] => Array ( [TICK] => 2196 [KD_AIRL] => GA [JUM] => 4590702968.99 ) [JT ] => Array ( [TICK] => 967 [KD_AIRL] => JT [JUM] => 891808457.39 ) [SJY] => Array ( [TICK] => 172 [KD_AIRL] => SJY [JUM] => 210378119 ) [GAC] => Array ( [TICK] => 130 [KD_AIRL] => GAC [JUM] => 183431300 ) [GA] => Array ( [TICK] => 60 [KD_AIRL] => GA [JUM] => 74070040 ) [AK ] => Array ( [TICK] => 45 [KD_AIRL] => AK [JUM] => 50256768 ) [JT] => Array ( [TICK] => 46 [KD_AIRL] => JT [JUM] => 35118000 ) ...) There is GA writen twice